# Deleting elements based on condition with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input id="img" type="file" name="img" accept="image/*">
```

And this is the `JQuery` code:

```
$('#img').change(function(){

    if($('#this').val() === '') { 

        $("#subm").remove();

    }  else {

         $('<button id="subm" type="submit">Press</button>').insertAfter('#advice');

   }

});
```

I'm trying check if the `input file` is empty, if is empty, and exist a button called `subm`, I delete it, but if the `input file` has a file, I create that bottom. The problem is that, if there's a `subm`botton, because I select file, and after I change the `input`, let it empty, `JQuery` doesn't delete it.

How can I delete a button, created by `JQuery`, if an `input file` is empty?

Thank's advance!

Comment: You should always have a button. If the input is empty, you might disable or even hide it, but there is no reason to remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('#this')` should be `$(this)`, `$('#this')` matches an element with `id=this`

Answer (score 3):

Unless you actually have an element with an id of "this", you probably meant to use the `this` keyword instead:

```
$('#img').change(function(){
    // this will be the #img that fired the change event
    if($(this).val() === '') {
        $("#subm").remove();
    }  else {
         $('<button id="subm" type="submit">Press</button>').insertAfter('#advice');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<input id="img" type="file" name="img" accept="image/*">
<button id="subm" type="submit">Press</button>
```

```js
$('#img').change(function(){
    if(!this.value) { 
        $("#subm").hide();
    } else {
        $("#subm").show();
    }
}).change(); // trigger event to init
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that the value of `this` can also change depending on the context it is being used in with javascript and jQuery. You should be fine now, however in more complex situations, you could run into issues

The best practice for this situation is to create another variable, typically called `self` immediately.

```
$('#img').change(function () {
    var self = this;
    // self will now ALWAYS be the #img that fired the change event.
    if ($(self).val() === '') {
        $("#subm").hide();
    } else {
        $("#subm").show();
    }
});
```

The issue happens if you use another function lower down, then `this` would now refer to the `this` in the lower function. Define a new variable for `self` whenever you step inside a new function so that you will always lock into what `this` is. (And don't forget to have those variable names be unique.)